# Video recording software for Linux

Tags: linux, video, offline

I want to make Videos for [Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/home/myvideos).

Currently I use VLC for that, but its complicated in this aspect and Vimeo tells me that I should use other settings for my camera in order to be able to show better video. But I don't understand the settings VLC presents me to make that happen.

The video I currently upload are of medium quality and I know that the camera can do better (a friend has the same and when we videochat the resolution is better).

So, I'm looking for a software that can record a video from my usb-webcam. It needs to be able to make at least HD 720p Video with 30 fps. Better would be preferred.

**Must haves:**

- Linux Desktop Software.
- Must work offline.

**Strongly preferred:**

- Simple UX. The less I need to think about it, the better.
- FLOSS Licence.

**Nice to have:**

- Gratis
- Simple Video editing elements (display an image instead of the video stream, cut the 'uhhm's and 'well's)

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to recommend Open Broadcaster Software. I've been using it for some time now and it's been working out great. It's available for not only Linux but also Windows and Macs. It can record from USB webcams and can record in  HD 720p Video with 30 fps (assuming for webcam can support that:). It can work on and offline and is open source. It has a pretty simple UI (see the screenshot below).

## [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/) ([open source](https://github.com/jp9000/OBS))

> Open Broadcaster Software is free and open source software for video recording and live streaming. Supported features include:
>
> - Encoding using H264 (x264) and AAC. Support for Intel Quick Sync    Video (QSV) and NVENC.
> - Unlimited number of scenes and sources.
> - Live    RTMP streaming to Twitch, YouTube, DailyMotion, Hitbox and more.
> - File    output to MP4 or FLV.
> - GPU-based game capture for high performance    game streaming.
> - DirectShow capture device support (webcams, capture    cards, etc).
> - Windows 8 high speed monitor capture support.
> - Bilinear    or lanczos3 resampling.
>
> [image: OBS Screenshot]

Comment: I could not make it work on my machine, yet. Seems like I have the wrong OpenGL Version, yet I got no info on how to fix it. Looks good on paper, though. In Systems that are compatible (e.G. Ubuntu) that looks like a good program.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs Hmm, it's pretty popular software that should work on all distributions of Linux, what are you running specifically?

Comment: Debian Jessy, 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3 (2016-01-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @AngeloFuchs I honestly don't have all that much knowledge & experience with OpenGL but the best I could do is send you this way and see if you could reinstall it: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Linux